# Using the output of diff to create the patch

Tags: diff, patch

I have something like this

```
src/sim/simulate.cc
41d40
< #include "mem/mem-interface.h"
90,91d88
<             dram_print_stats_common(curTick/500);
<
src/mem/physical.hh
52d51
<   public:
55,56d53
<       public:
<
58a56,57
>       public:
>
61,62c60,61
<         virtual bool recvTiming(PacketPtr pkt); //baoyg
<
---
```

I believe this was created using the diff command in a source tree. What I want is to create the patch using that output, and to apply the same changes to my source tree.

Comment: The answers to this question all seem off-topic now that it has been edited to show a different diff format than the original question.

Answer (score 80):

I believe that `diff -u oldfile newfile > a.patch` is used to create patch files, although some other switched may be thrown in as well (-N?).

Edit: OK, 4 years later and finally going to explain what the switches mean:

`-u` creates a [Unified](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Unified-Format.html) diff.  Unified diffs are the kind of diffs that the patch program expects to get as input.  You can also specify a number after the `u` (min 3, default 3) to increase the number of lines output.  This is in case 3 lines isn't unique enough to pinpoint just one spot in the program.

`-N` treats absent files as being empty, which means it will produce a lot of additional content if one of the files is empty (or see next point).

Also, `newfile` and `oldfile` can both be directories instead of single files.  You'll likely want the `-r` argument for this to recurse any subdirectories.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to get the same patch output as SVN or git diff, given two different files or folders:

```sh
diff -Naur file1.cpp file2.cpp
```

Comment: @Neil -N is for diffing folders

Comment: @kevin I don't think that's accurate; it changes how it treats empty files. (Which might only be *relevant* for folders--but still, your comment makes it sound like `-N` is what makes the diff recursive, which is in fact the point of `-r`.)

Comment: And how exactly it is explicitly related to SVN?

Comment: @VictorYarema You are right, all SVCs I know use this format. I think the edited version now reflects that.

Answer (score 3):

What you have there is a non-unified diff.  patch can read it, but will be unable to make context matches and is more likely to make mistakes.

Comment: So what should I do?, do the changes manually, I have a bunch of them or give it a try with patch?. Is the right command to create the patch the one provided by R. Bemrose?.

Comment: Make a backup, of course.  Then apply the patches to one specific file at a time (non-unified diffs do not tell which file(s) they apply to).  diff -u is a virtually universal standard, other options provide more robustness and compatibility with other systems, as Andrei pointed out re svn diff

Answer (score 2):

That *is* a (partial) patch file, though it would have been better if they provided you with a unified diff output.

The main issue with that patch is that it doesn't mention which files are being modified, and since there is no context provided, the files must be *exact*, patch will be unable to allow for minor changes in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the diff in the original post to a patch file named `test.patch` then run

```
patch <original file> test.patch
```

@Sparr and @Arafangion point out that this works best if you have the exact original file used to create the original diff.